# Woocommerce display price without formatting

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

### What I Want

I want to display the prices in the product page exactly as inputed. So for eg: if for a product I give price as 70.000 and another price as 70. I want to display exactly as entered. So regular price for first will be displayed as 70.000 and for second product price will be displayed as 70.

The reason for this is for certain products I want to display the decimal points and for some I don't want decimal points. So setting decimal point to 3 in woocommerce settings to 3 is not an option.

### What I Tried

I tried modifying `wc_price` function in wc-formatting `get_price_html` function in absctract-wc-product.php

But it seems like the price is formatted before. How can I achieve this? I'm new to wordpress and would like some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `get_price()` instead of `get_price_html()`. You can call the function on any woocommerce template like this

```
$product->get_price();
```